# what do I need on server side to accept file uploaded by wget with simple HTTP POST?

Tags: php, linux, apache, bash, wget

I have an OM2P access point with a limited set of utilities. And I'm implementing a script for periodically sending logs to the server. For file sending only wget and scp could be used. there are no curl, ftp, sftp, wput and others. So the only valid solution is to upload file with wget --post-file  (HTTP POST). But what do I need on server side (I have an Apache2.4) to process this request and store uploaded file in directory? Should it be processed from PHP side or there is some simple cgi-bin or any other handler to do it? Unfortunately I was not able to find the answer fast after googling. From my point of view it should be something very simple. But as soon as I'm not a server-side guy - I don't know ;)

Comment: SCP is a subset of SSH. Have you looked at [SSH2](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything specifically on server side if you want to accept file uploaded by wget with simple HTTP POST. It should be processed from PHP itself.